# How to stop the timer in flutter?

Tags: timer, flutter

I have created a timer in flutter and everything works fine. Now I can't figure out how to dismiss the timer after I started it.
The docs say that you can cancel it by calling `void cancel()` but I don't understand the implementation.

How am I supposed to call it?
And is it the right approach?

```
  static const timeout = const Duration(seconds: 5);
  static const ms = const Duration(milliseconds: 1);

  startTimeout([int milliseconds]) {
    var duration = milliseconds == null ? timeout : ms * milliseconds;
    return new Timer(duration, handleTimeout);
  }

  void handleTimeout() {  // callback function
    Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => new ScorePage(quiz.score, quiz.length)),(Route route) => route == null);
    return;
  }
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just keep a reference to the time and cancel it when you don't need it anymore

```
var timer = startTimeout(100);
...
timer.cancel();
```

Comment: now it says that "context" cant be accessed  from a static method

Comment: That's unrelated to the timer question. You probably call `handleTimeout` from somewhere where `context` is not or not yet available, but your question doesn't contain that code.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I need to cancel timer when offline, after online I need to start timer.. Is it possible?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer full question and code https://stackoverflow.com/q/56951639/9139407

Answer (score 0):

in case you are using periodic just try this

```
startTimeout( BuildContext context, [int? milliseconds]) {
  var duration = const Duration(seconds: 1);
  var currentSeconds;

Timer _timer=Timer.periodic(duration, (timer) async {
   var userIsLogged=false;
    // print(timer.tick);
    currentSeconds = timer.tick;
    if (timer.tick >= 25)
    {
      timer.cancel();

       
// some code here once timed out

      }

  });

return _timer;
}
```

then from a place you called it just add bellow code to cancel

```
startTimeout.cancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just start the timer like,

```
Timer _timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {});
```

later if you need to stop or cancel the timer in any case, just call this function:

```
_timer.cancel();
```