# how to stop/dispose timer when offline?

Tags: flutter, dart

I called some methods using timer..I used 4 timers. I need to call only when **online**. how to stop or disable timer when offile?

```
  void connectionChanged(dynamic hasConnection) {
    setState(() {
      isOffline = !hasConnection;
      if(!isOffline){
        timer1 = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
          checkRefresh();
          checkQuick(_url, tokens);
        });
        timer3 = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) {
          globals.getQuick().then((onValue) {
            setState(() {
              isQuick = onValue;
            });
          });
        });
        timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (Timer t) {
          submitRequestSave(_url, tokens);
        });
        timer2 = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (Timer t) {
          storeSync(_url, tokens);
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

I used dispose when navigate

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer1.cancel();
    timer2.cancel();
    timer3.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you call `cancel()` inside `if (isOffline) {}`?

Comment: When exactly is `connectionChanged` is called?

Comment: @HugoPassos you told me like this? ```if(isOffline){timer.cacel()}else{ if(!isOffline){
        timer1 = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
        });}```

Comment: @Nae inside initState() ```ConnectionStatusSingleton connectionStatus =
        ConnectionStatusSingleton.getInstance();
    _connectionChangeStream =
        connectionStatus.connectionChange.listen(connectionChanged);
    connectionChanged(connectionStatus.hasConnection);```