# How to cancel a Timer initiated in a function?

Tags: flutter, timer

I have a periodic timer on my app.
After I create it, I need to cancel it.

But I can't find a way to do that.

This solution ([How to stop the timer in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51559508/how-to-stop-the-timer-in-flutter)) doesn't work for me.

If I name a timer - I create it immediately on app launch, but I need to create it later on a push of a button - that's why I am using a void function to create it.
Once I create it in a void function - I cannot access it from anywhere else in my code since it exists only inside my void Function.
So there is no way to call timer.cancel();

Please help.

```
void startTimer(controller) {
    Timer timer = Timer.periodic(
      timerLogic.timerDuration,
      (timer) {
        timerLogic.timerFunction;
        controller.reset();
        controller.forward();
        notifyListeners();
      },
    );
  }

timer.cancel(); //doesn't work
```

Comment: `startTimer` has to return a `Timer`, not `void` - and you will need that returned `Timer` to call `cancel()` method on it

Comment: sure, your welcome